# Handle global Angular 4 errors

Tags: angular

We need a way to handle global Angular errors including incorrect http calls like 401 or 500.

I see that there is an ErrorHandle class that catches the global Angular Exceptions but that class does not detects the incorrect(status 500 for example) http calls. So is there another way of handling those 2 types of errors or I need to create some sort of delegation from them to another custom service ?

Comment: make use of `angular interceptors` [link](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor)

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Angular 4, you could use the new `HttpClient`, and simply write an interceptor for your HTTP responses.
More details and examples in the [Angular docs for HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http).

**EDIT: added example**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(req).do(event => {}, err => {
            if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse && err.status == 401) {
                // handle 401 errors
            }

            if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse && err.status == 500) {
                // handle 500 errors
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: it classifies much as a comment , please give an example for the statement

Comment: Is there a way where the interceptor can throw an exception and the global ErrorHandler can then handle that error ?
For example "throw new Error('err')" in some of the "if" statements ?

Answer (score -1):

When your service returns the observable back to wherever you called it from you can do something like this:

```
this.myService.doSomething().subscribe(
   successfulPayload => { //do stuff with the good response },
   error => this._apiErrorHandler(error));
```

Then in the _apiErrorHandler you can dispatch the error to the store so that other components can do whatever they need to do with knowing there was an error.

```
private _apiErrorHandler(payload) {
   this.store.dispatch({ type: 'API_ERROR', payload });
}
```

Since this is an api error you know it will have a code like the status 500 and so the payload has a status property and a statusText property (payload.status, and payload.statusText)